# How to detect this CSS bug in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, feature-detection

I am using a CSS-based approach to crop images to fit a specific aspect ratio. On the back-end, I access the images height and width, and absolutely position the image within a span-wrapper given the difference in aspect-ratio between the image and the space it's being cropped to. The back-end code is irrelevant to my concern here, but the front end code works like this:

```
<a href="some-link-url">
    <span class="croppedImageWrapper" style="height:115px;width:115px;" title="(Some title)">
    <img src="some-url-for-img-with-aspect-ratio=1.36" style="height:100%;top:0px;left:-28px;" />
    </span>
</a>

.croppedImageWrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.croppedImageWrapper img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

It works well in all browsers I need to support, except for IE7: when I place a `.croppedImageWrapper` inside a link, it seems to *cover up* the link, making it un-clickable. I have been dealing with this with a simple check in jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 7)
```

... I can then attach a click-event to the span, grab the href of its parent link, and redirect. But now that I've up-graded to jQuery 1.9.1, this no longer works -- `$.browser` is deprecated in favor of feature detection.

***So my question is: ***

How could one use feature (bug) detection to sniff out this bug? Or will I just have to hack back in an IE version detector?

Comment: did you use `jquery-migrate` plugin along with 1.9.1 ?

Comment: I always found with ie7 that I needed to add a 50x50 transparent background image (repeated) to some anchors to make them clickable. Not sure why though

Comment: In my opinion, IE7 is bad enough that using browser detection is worth it - there's really no way to do so without odd CSS hacks that cause errors in other browsers (which _is_ browser detection anyway) and overall makes your files more cluttered.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: no -- and I'm not partial to bringing in an extra 8kb (minified) .js file just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this in one of my projects, a simple replacement for $.browser without having to include the entire jQuery Migrate script.

http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2013/01/16/jquery-1-9-is-out-and-browser-has-been-removed-a-fast-workaround/

```
jQuery.browser = {};
jQuery.browser.mozilla = /mozilla/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && !/webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
jQuery.browser.webkit = /webkit/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
jQuery.browser.opera = /opera/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
jQuery.browser.msie = /msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

You'd also need to use that in conjunction with:

```
navigator.appVersion
```

Comment: OK, I can use use `navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.")!=-1` -- but I'd prefer to know how I could  sniff out the bug, rather than targeting the browser-version.